# "Could not get audio input for record source 7" : SipAudioCall.start() Android 2.3.3 on Samsung GT-I9001 (Samsung Galaxy S Plus) doesn't work

Tags: android, audio, voip

I'm trying to start sample VoIP application on my Samsung Galaxy S. In the emulator application works just like a charm but during test on the phone I get :

```
09-20 13:41:57.874: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getDeviceForStrategy() strategy 3, device 2
09-20 13:41:57.874: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 0 delayMs 0
09-20 13:41:57.874: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0 or null device for output 1
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 1, device 2
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getOutput() stream 0, samplingRate 0, format 0, channels c, flags 0
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 1, device 2
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getOutput() stream 0, samplingRate 8000, format 1, channels 4, flags 0
09-20 13:41:57.884: WARN/AudioPolicyManager(114): getInput() invalid input source 7
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getDeviceForInputSource()input source 7, device 00000000
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): getInput() inputSource 7, samplingRate 8000, format 1, channels 10, acoustics 0
09-20 13:41:57.884: ERROR/AudioRecord(4228): Could not get audio input for record source 7
09-20 13:41:57.884: ERROR/AudioGroup(4228): cannot initialize audio device
09-20 13:41:57.884: VERBOSE/AudioPolicyManager(114): releaseOutput()
```

The result is that nothing is captured by the phone and no voice is played through the speaker.

Thank you for help.

Comment: duplicate :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962536/could-not-get-audio-input-for-record-source-1-when-trying-to-initialize-audior

Comment: may help too :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461383/recording-in-android-giving-expections/7028077#7028077

Comment: I'm trying the SipDemo app and getting the same error on a huawey api16. And I cannot find any solution or any hint how to fix this. Any ideas since 2011 :-/